# How do php echo use for smart phones

Tags: javascript, php, android, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter for my project and I want to know how codeigniter can use for echo to shows a message that send to a mobile phone. it shows the php code instead of the message.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HF0xf.png

```
$this->sms->message('Thank you for your order Your order has been received and will be processed shortly<br>Your order ID: <?php echo $order_id ?>');
```

Comment: How is it sent? Show your code. Apparently, the PHP is not executed, it is just treated as a String. As said below, it doesn't seem to have anything to do with Android and JavaScript.

Comment: It appears to be sent as SMS, not related to Android if so.

Comment: by the looks of that image, your file isn't `.php` - It's showing PHP code and not being properly parsed. This has nothing to do with smart phones. This is serverside processing, not client-side. Show your codes.

Comment: I Posted my code under the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already in PHP, therefore you need to remove the `<?php` and `?>` tags.

Plus, variables do not get parsed in single quotes, therefore you need to use double quotes.

```
$this->sms->message("Thank you for ... shortly<br>Your order ID: $order_id");
```

I also hope that your files are a `.php` extension.

For more information on single/double quotes, read the following Q&A on Stack:

- [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: Thanks for the edit blex. I need to add something but I will keep yours.

Comment: Sure, I just thought it would be nice not to have to scroll to see the changes you made ;) +1

Comment: @blex Je me demande s'il y a une section francophone sur Stack. Je n'ai jamais regarder/chercher. Sinon, ce serait bien d'en avoir une. *arrivederci!*

Comment: I don't believe there is one in French, but there is one in [Russian](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/). Peut-être plus tard, but it does not bother me, I think having a common site in English for every country is the best way to gather the most answers and questions. Furthermore, it's a good way to practice our English :) PS: J'adore la Poutine ! - Non, je ne réduis pas le Canada à la Poutine ;)

Comment: @blex Indeed. The English language is the most widely used, and more so in business. Ouais, notre poutine est la meilleure. Le secret est dans la sauce ;-) prend soin.

Answer (score 0):

I Generally Use this code. Change the settings.
I got this link through 'mysmsmantra'

```
$OrderMessage=urlencode("Dear Customer, Order $OrderId of Rs. $TotalPayableAmount is accepted by Sangakara. Thank You");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 
    "http://bulksms.mysmsmantra.com:8080/WebSMS/SMSAPI.jsp?username=sangakara&password=password&sendername=sendername&mobileno=$MobileNo&message=$OrderMessage"
);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
```